# regex to capture multiple groups separated by an initial delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like this:

```
|T1| This is some text for the first tag |T2| this is some text for the second tag
```

I need to parse out the tags and the text that is associated with each one. The tags are not known ahead of time but they are delimited by `\|\w+\|`.

I know there is something I can do here as far as capturing groups and so on but after messing around in powershell the best I can come up with is to first isolate each pairing using `\|\w+\|.*`with the ExplicitCapture option and then parse out the tag and text from there.

But that is doing double the work and totally not super-cool haxor. What's the regex-pro way to do this?

**Edit:** Actually I realize that it's late and I misread my results. The above doesn't actually work so now I don't even have a bad solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\|(?<tag>\w+)\|(?<text>[^|]*)
```

Matches `|T1| This is some text for the first tag |T2| this is some text for the second tag`

into

```
 |T1| This is some text for the first tag 
 |T2| this is some text for the second tag
```

**EDIT**:
Use Regex Groups to get parts of match;

```
var tagName = match.Groups["tag"].Value;
var text = match.Groups["text"].Value;
```

Swithed to named groups instead of numbered

Comment: Yeah, I got that far eventually but this still seems like a somewhat bad solution. you still have to then parse the tag out from each line therefore running the regex engine on each line twice and selecting the same stuff twice. Also it will fail if any pipe characters are used at all even if they don't match the `\|\w+\|` delimiter pattern. (though granted I can figure out a way to select against that)

Comment: Cool - shouldn't it be possible to capture the text for each tag at the same time? Unless I'm misunderstanding how the regex engine works it should be processed and captured somewhere already.

Comment: Oh that is awesome, totally did not know you could do that